# pandas save date in ISO format?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm trying to generate a Pandas DataFrame where date_range is an index. Then save it to a CSV file so that the dates are written in ISO-8601 format.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

NumberOfSamples = 10
dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=NumberOfSamples,freq='90S')
df3 = DataFrame(index=dates)
df3.to_csv('dates.txt', header=False)
```

The current output to dates.txt is:

```
2013-01-01 00:00:00
2013-01-01 00:01:30
2013-01-01 00:03:00
2013-01-01 00:04:30
...................
```

I'm trying to get it to look like:

```
2013-01-01T00:00:00Z
2013-01-01T00:01:30Z
2013-01-01T00:03:00Z
2013-01-01T00:04:30Z
....................
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `datetime.strftime` and call `map` on the index:

```
In [72]:

NumberOfSamples = 10
import datetime as dt
dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=NumberOfSamples,freq='90S')
df3 = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
df3.index = df3.index.map(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'))
df3
Out[72]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2013-01-01T00:00:00Z, 2013-01-01T00:01:30Z, 2013-01-01T00:03:00Z, 2013-01-01T00:04:30Z, 2013-01-01T00:06:00Z, 2013-01-01T00:07:30Z, 2013-01-01T00:09:00Z, 2013-01-01T00:10:30Z, 2013-01-01T00:12:00Z, 2013-01-01T00:13:30Z]
```

Alternatively and better in my view (thanks to @unutbu) you can pass a format specifier to `to_csv`:

```
df3.to_csv('dates.txt', header=False, date_format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

Comment: I think it might be more reliable to use the `isoformat()` method from `datetime` rather than `strftime()` with a custom format. Something like `df3.index = df3.index.to_series().apply(dt.datetime.isoformat)`

Answer (score 2):

#### With [`pd.Index.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

If you're sure that all your dates are UTC, you can hardcode the format:

```
df3.index = df3.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

which gives you `2013-01-01T00:00:00Z` and so on. Note that the "Z" denotes UTC!

#### With [`pd.Timestamp.isoformat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.isoformat.html) and [`pd.Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html):

```
df3.index = df3.index.map(lambda timestamp: timestamp.isoformat())
```

This gives you `2013-01-01T00:00:00`. If you attach a timezone to your dates first (e.g. by passing `tz="UTC"` to `date_range`), you'll get: `2013-01-01T00:00:00+00:00` which also conforms to ISO-8601 but is a different notation. This should work for any `dateutil` or `pytz` timezone, leaving no room for ambiguity when clocks switch from daylight saving to standard time.